# React - Organizing Routes - Issue directing to a new page

Tags: reactjs, components

I want my SignIn component to render on its own without any of the other components being rendered.

How could I have this done.

Below is my app.js

```
function App() {
  return (
    <>
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Navbar />
        <Stack direction="row" spacing={1} justifyContent="flex-start" style={{ backgroundColor: "#f0f4f8" }} sx={{ borderTopColor: '#d9e2ec', borderTopStyle: 'solid', borderTopWidth: '0.1em' }}>
          <Sidebar />
          <div className='pages'>
            <Routes>
              <Route path="/api/jobs/:id" element={<JobSelectOne />} />
              <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
              <Route path="/create" element={<AddJob />} />
              <Route path="/profile" element={<Profile />} />
              <Route path="/signin" element={<SignIn />} />
            </Routes>
          </div>
        </Stack>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
</>
```

Answer (score 0):

These are Private/Protected Routes. It requires a complex explanation and I prefer to add a link: [Private Routes](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-router-private-routes/). But it could be "shortly version":

```
const ProtectedRoute = ({ user, children }) => {
  if (!user) {
    return <Navigate to="/signin" replace />;
  }

  return children;
};
```